# Passing objects to functions

Tags: r

I am currently working on user defined functions aimed at modelling empirical data and I have problems with objects / parameters passed to the function:

```
bestModel <- function(k=4L, R2=0.994){
  print(k)   # here, everything is still fine

  lmX <- mixlm::lm(getLinearModelFunction(k), data)
  best <- mixlm::best.subsets(lmX, nbest=1)
  .
  .
  .
}
```

At first, everything works as expected, but as soon as I want to pass the parameter `k` to another user defined function `getLinearModelFunction()`, an error is thrown:

```
Error in getLinearModelFunction(k) : object 'k' not found
```

It doesn't help, if I am assigning a new parameter, e. g. `l <- k` and try to pass that on. The parameter doesn't seem to be available for the other function. I ran into this problem not only with primitive data types, but as well complex structures. On command line, everything works, as long as the objects are in my workspace.

To sum it up: Passing parameters work only within that function, but calls of other functions from there onwards result in error. Why? And: What to do about it?

EDIT:
While trying to resolve the problem, it gets really weird. I stripped down all functions:

```
functionA <- function(data, k){
      lmX <- mixlm::lm(functionB(k), data)
      summary(lmX)

      # best <- mixlm::best.subsets(lmX,nbest=1)
    }


    functionB <- function(k=4){
      if(k==1){
        return(formula("raw ~ L1"))
      }else if(k==2){
        return(formula("raw ~ L1 + L2"))
      }else if(k==3){
        return(formula("raw ~ L1 + L2 + L3 "))
      }else if(k==4){
        return(formula("raw ~ L1 + L2 + L3 + L4"))
      }
    }
```

Let's say, we have a data.frame d with the variables raw, L1, L2, L3, L4 ... As long, as there is the commenting # before best, it works. As soon as it is removed, calling functionA(d, 3) results in

```
Error in functionB(k) : object 'k' not found
```

Even, though k doesn't play a role in that function and before that, it worked.

Comment: Does `getLinearModelFunction` work as you expect when you call it on its own? I have no problems calling a self-defined function (using parameter *k*) from within your `bestModel` function.

Comment: maybe you might try to replace `k` by `eval(parse(text = k)` to make the internal function work with the desired object / content.

Comment: Many thanks for the comments. The getLinearModelFunction works well, when called directly from the command line. eval(parse... doesn't solve the problem. All user defined functions are present in the workspace. BTW: I use RStudio and they are shown in the Global Environment. Are there different environments?

Comment: The error comes from within `getLinearModelFunction`, not within `bestModel`, and we don't know what that function contains since the question did not include it but it somewhere contains a reference to `k` without ever defining `k`.

Comment: The getLinearModelFunction is pretty simple:
<pre># Generate linear regression model function based on k
getLinearModelFunction <- function(k=4){
  if(k<1){
    message("Parameter k out of range; setting to 1")
    k <- 1
  } else if(k>6){
    message("Parameter k out of range; setting to 6")
    k <- 6
  }
  
  if(k==1){
    return(formula("raw ~ L1 + A1 + L1A1"))
  }else if(k==2){
    return(formula("raw ~ L1 + L2 + A1 + A2 + L1A1 + L1A2 + L2A1 + L2A2"))
  }
.
.
.
}<code>

Comment: I edited the example. Somehow, the error only shows up when best.subsets from the mixlm package is used.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, indeed, this was an environment thing. The solution is to get the current environment and to take the object from there:

```
functionA <- function(data, k){
   e <- environment()
   lmX <- mixlm::lm(functionB(e$k), e$data)
   summary(lmX)

   best <- mixlm::best.subsets(lmX,nbest=1)
 }
```

This is usually not a problem, when directly working with are packages. The objects usually are in the global environments then. When working with functions, each function has its' own environment. I managed to solve this while starting to learn about packaging the code: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html